# Avoid JHipster user login

Tags: jhipster

I want to avoid the user authentication part (at least for a few REST-API). How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 4):

Edit `SecurityConfiguration` java class in your generated project and use `permitAll(`) on the few URLs you want to unprotect:

```
   .antMatchers("/api/myresource").permitAll()
```

Refer to Spring security docs for details.

Comment: Thanks, Gaël Marziou !!